# Stop/Start button binding in WP7

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7.1

There's a button for playing music on the form and a media element. The button is used for play/stop the music.

Is it possible (and how) to draw an arrow or a square inside the button by clicking in XAML? It must depends on the state of the media element (if it's playing or not). If it's impossible how to do it in code behind?

P.S. In other words it the music is playing the button must displays a square, otherwise it's must be an arrow (like a triangle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the background image of the button through code.

```
    if(mediaplays)
    {
        ImageSource img = new BitmapImage(new Uri("imageurl", UriKind.Relative));
        ImageBrush imgb = new ImageBrush();
        imgb.ImageSource = img;

        btn.Background = imgb;//btn is the name of the button
    }
```